# M1 / M2 Pro vs Max heat and energy consumption

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power, apple-silicon

I know this is going to sound ridiculous, but I'm primarily looking at the 16 inch MBP for the larger screen real estate. Granted, I always want my chips to be fastest, etc. but I have a mini-datacenter in my home where I do most of my compute intensive tasks.

So here is the question - given that I mostly want to have a large screen with ~16 terminals open to do coding, could bumping up to the Max (M1 or M2) actually hurt me here in terms of heating / power draw? I'd rather sacrifice the performance for the sake of reduced noise / heat / battery if it came to it. However, if the extra cores would just sit there and be 'free' extra compute when I wanted to run something locally I'd be all about it.

So will bumping up to the M1 (or M2) Max cause increased heat, noise, or power draw compared to the 'base' chip that would come with a MBP 16 inch?

Comment: If you just run Terminals and do all the heavy lifting in your in-house data center, even a Raspberry would probably do :-)

Comment: My raspberry pis don’t run my neovim clang formatters in real time so I just have to use plain old vim on those sadly. I do have a cluster of those in my datacenter that I run ARM centric optimized simulations on tho XD.

Answer (score 2):

The M1 Max has the same 10-core CPU as the M1 Pro. So there is no difference in performance on that basis.

The Max has more GPU cores, of course (as well as twice the memory bandwidth and RAM capacity), so it can perform graphic-intensive processes and handle more data faster.

Some reports suggest that the Max uses slightly more battery, but that may depend on usage.

I have the 16" M1 Pro, and I've yet to find anything that will make the fans move at all!

If you're not working in video, nor an environment where every second costs money: I'd suggest the Pro is sufficient.

There are no M2 16-inch MBPs at present; though rumours suggest they may be  imminent. *(Don't they always?)*